# Pytorch expand not trainable?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I have a sequence model and I want to concatenate a same piece of small embedding to the input. Specifically, that looks like

if the original embedding is ABCDEFG, the expected one would be

A  B  C  D  E  F  G

X  X  X  X  X  X  X

From a coding aspect, that's something like:

```
embed_0_out = embed_0(input_0) # sequence input
embed_1_out = embed_1(input_1) # single input

embed_combined_out = torch.cat([embed_0_out, embed_1_out.unsqueeze(1).expand(batch_size, input_0_len, 10)], 2))
```

However, it seems like the weight for `embed_1` is not changing after each iteration, suggesting that it is not trainable. Thus, is there any way to make it trainable?

Comment: That looks ok (in that torch.expand will properly backpropagate). So without further insight into your code, I really cannot say why the gradients are not properly back propagated. Could you please share a larger section?